# Adding line breaks within query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns results from multiple tables

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tc.comment) AS comments
FROM
  people AS p LEFT JOIN comments AS tc
  ON tc.pID = p.id
WHERE
  p.projID = $project_id
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  p.name
```

When it returns comments it puts them all together into one column and when I output them on a page it is hard to delineate where one ends and another begins. Is there a way to insert some sort of blank line after each comment while building this query? Normally I'd do it in PHP when I output results but in this case I don't know where the breaks should be.

Comment: Does `GROUP_CONCAT(tc.comment SEPARATOR "\n") AS comments` work?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` should separate the rows with commas.  So, in PHP you can try to replace commas with newlines.

Comment: isn't group_concat escaped separator inside own values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpy add a delimiter after your tc.comment like this:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tc.comment, " | ") AS comments
FROM
  people AS p LEFT JOIN comments AS tc
  ON tc.pID = p.id
WHERE
  p.projID = $project_id
GROUP BY
  p.id,
  p.name
```

This will put a | between each tc.comment but will leave a comma as a separator. Use

```
GROUP_CONCAT(tc.comment SEPARATOR " | ")
```

if you want to replace the comma rather than adding to the element.

You could, alternately (more to your specific point) add "\n" for new lines or "<br />" if you're outputting to a web page.

Comment: Actually, now that I go test this, you might want do your delimiter first as GROUP_CONCAT puts a comma between the output fields.

Comment: I just noticed that too... Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to get rid of those commas? I think I'll just add some unique deliniator and then use PHP to replace it with breaks.

Comment: Yep -- turns out the comment about GROUP_CONCAT(tc.comment SEPARATOR "\n") will replace rather than add to the element. just updated my answer to include that.